# What is a good way to describe someone falling and feeling the strong wind pushing them down?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-choice

I screamed. My whole body was falling down in complete darkness. I could feel the strong wind pushing me down. I had my eyes opened for a while but closed them, feeling no use in having them opened since I couldn’t see anything.

Comment: [my body was falling down is wrong; "My whole body was falling"]

Answer (score 1):

Compression

Which means being pushed or squeezed into a smaller space

Example:

I screamed. My whole body was falling down in complete darkness. I could feel the strong wind **compressing** me, pushing me down. I had my eyes opened for a while but closed them, feeling no use in having them opened since I couldn’t see anything.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compress

Comment: Yes, good but falling, not falling down.

Comment: Yes, @Lambie, it could do with a comma after 'down'. As in: falling, down, in complete darkness. Which would cause the reader to pause and feel that silent movement for a moment. Or yes, leave that out. But it's not my fault;  I didn't write that prose. And usually when I offer writing suggestions or endeavour to propagate the beauty of the English language, the techie language peeps jump out of their armchairs ;)